# How to replace eval() during monkey patching?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, eval, mozilla, browser-extension

I develop a browser extension that applies the patch to the original function as follows:

```
eval('sourceFunction=' + sourceFunction.toString().replace(/foo/g, 'bar'));
```

Reviewers of the Mozilla Add-ons Catalog ban the use of the eval method as unsafe. Is there an alternative way to similarly patch the function?

Comment: You have to use the original function's contents as a string?

Comment: if 'foo' is an identifier within the function that resolves outside the scope of the function, then yes. Otherwise, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use the original function's contents as a string, then no, probably not.

While you could use `new Function` instead:

```
sourceFunction = new Function("return " + sourceFunction.toString().replace(/*...*/))();
```

...any sensible policy that bans `eval` will also probably ban `new Function`..